# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2014

I am writing to develop a program concerning stock of a firm.

I have variable quantity in stock in int, ı am trying to get all quantity and compare with the result written on textbox.

I am using the following code:

```
SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection("server=.;database=DB_TEST;trusted_connection=true"); - SERVER CONNECTION


SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("Select SUM(Quantity) from Stock where ProductID='" + cmbxProductID.SelectedValue + "'", sqlcon); - GETTING TOTAL QUANTITY FROM DATABASE - quantity in int

sqlcon.Open(); - SQL CONNECTION OPEN

textBox1.Text = sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); -- transfering total quantity to textbox1

int result=int.Parse(textBox1.Text); -- CONVERT CONTENT OF TEXTBOX to ınt

if (result == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Stock is not adequate");
        }

        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        sqlcon.Close()

        MessageBox.Show("Stock is OK");
```

Comment: On which line exactly? I don't see any illegal usage of `==` operator in your code. Are you sure your `ProductID` column type is character? It sounds like a numeric column but.. Where do you open your connection btw? And you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Also use _using statement_ to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.

Comment: Try opening the connection using `sqlcon.Open();` before executing any statements.

Comment: Also consider using `TryParse` instead of `Parse`. The later throws an exception if it cannot parse the string, and you're not catching any. `TryParse` does not throw.

Comment: i dont see any illegal usage of `==`, are you sure this code does not work?what is your complette code?

Comment: Yes ıt throws error Error 1 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int' in line if(result == 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the result to a variable & not to textBox1. Then you can compare the variable value & textBox1 value

```
SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection("server=.;database=DB_TEST;" + 
                                     "trusted_connection=true");
SqlCommand sqlkmt = new SqlCommand("Select SUM(QUANTITY) from Stock " + 
                                   "where ProductID='" + 
                                    cmbxProductID.SelectedValue + "'",  sqlcon);                       
sqlcon.Open();
int result= sqlkmt.ExecuteScalar();
sqlcon.Close();
if (result == int.Parse(textBox1.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Stock in not adeqaute");
}
```

Mark if this was helpful

Comment: `int result= sqlkmt.ExecuteScalar().ToString();` that won't work ...

Comment: Hi! Since the variable "result" is integer, do not include ..ToString() in the statement.